# What keeps a reference on a function's nested class once the function returns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, reference

Consider this (Python 3):

```
class M(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        print('creating class {}'.format(name))
        return super().__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)

    def __del__(cls):
        print('deleting class {}'.format(cls.__name__))


def func():
    class A(metaclass=M):
        pass


func()
func()
func()
print('end')
```

The output is:

```
creating class A
creating class A
creating class A
end
deleting class A
deleting class A
deleting class A
```

This shows that once the function's nested class is created (when calling `func()`), something holds a reference on it even when the function returns.

What exactly holds such a reference? Is there any way to access the created class after `func()` returns?

Note: `sys.getrefcount(A)` just before the function returns returns 5.

Comment: Hey, this was marked as duplicate, but the "duplicate" question is not the same at all. I know what `__del__()` does, that's not the point. I have a very specific question here about nested class references.

Comment: Well, for starters, classes keep track of their subclasses. So if you check `object.__subclasses__()` you'll see three different Foo classes (same name, different objects). There likely are other places as well.